# get the same state for different requests

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

i have this action:

```
export const connectToServer = (url, config, method) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: CONNECTION_START});
    axios({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      data: config
    })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: CONNECTION_LOADING_SUCCESS, payload: response.data});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({type: CONNECTION_LOADING_ERROR, payload: error.response.data});
      })
  }
};
```

And 2 identical reducers:

```
const initialState = {
  data: null,
  isLoading: false,
  error: null
};

export const connectToServerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONNECTION_START :
      return {...state, isLoading: true};
    case CONNECTION_LOADING_SUCCESS :
      return {...state, isLoading: false, data: action.payload, error: null};
    case CONNECTION_LOADING_ERROR:
      return {...state, isLoading: false, data: null, error: action.payload};
    default :
      return state
  }
};

export const differentUrlConnectToServerReducerTest = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONNECTION_START :
      return {...state, isLoading: true};
    case CONNECTION_LOADING_SUCCESS :
      return {...state, isLoading: false, data: action.payload, error: null};
    case CONNECTION_LOADING_ERROR:
      return {...state, isLoading: false, data: null, error: action.payload};
    default :
      return state
  }
};
```

My store looks like this:

```
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  allUsersData: connectToServerReducer,
  testData: differentUrlConnectToServerReducerTest
});

const configureStore = () => createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default configureStore
```

Then i use redux hooks to get a state with data in my components

```
 const allUsersData = useSelector(state => state.allUsersData);
 const testData = useSelector(state => state.testData);
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

Finally i dispatch them

```
dispatch(connectToServer(`${BASE_URL}user/allUsersWithPets`, null, 'get'));
dispatch(connectToServer(`${BASE_URL}fakeUrl`, null, 'get'));
```

I receive a correct data in `allUsersData`, but also i receive it in `testData` but i should receive in `testData` an initial state(empty object), because url is a fake

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the reducers, use different initial states for example:

```
connectToServer.js
connectToServerTest.js
```

Or you can try to add the test object to the initial state of connectToServerReducer.(not a good solution though)

```
const initialState = {
  data: null,
  testData: null,
  isLoading: false,
  error: null
};
```

Remember that arrays affections won't assign values but addresses, so the "data" array is the same array in both the connectToServerReducer and connectToServerReducerTest.

Second problem, you are calling the same action name in both reducers, this causes them not only to share the same variable from the previous problem I told you, but they share the same value assigned to them as well.
Just change them to:

```
CONNECTION_TEST_LOADING_SUCCESS
CONNECTION_TEST_LOADING_ERROR
CONNECTION_TEST_START
```

PS:
instead of using:

```
export const connectToServer = (url, config, method) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
   ...
  }
}
```

Use:

```
  export const connectToServer = (url, config, method) => (dispatch) => {
       ...
      }
```

Comment: i separated the reducers into different files, and removed `return (dispatch)`, but still have the same problem. Maybe i have to separate actions too, like reducers?

Comment: @RomanKarpyshyn did you make different initial states?

Comment: , of course , 2 different files with different initial states. Its so strange :-)

Comment: Oh... I know why lol, Change the actions name, add TEST at the end maybe like: CONNECTION_TEST_LOADING_SUCCESS

Comment: noticed in logs that even if I don't dispatch second action with fake url, i still receive data from first.lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221555/discussion-between-med-amine-benyettou-and-roman-karpyshyn).